# Finder doesn’t see files on Android devices from MacBook Pro USB commections

Tags: macos, android

I have a Macbook Pro which I am trying to attach an Android device via USB (the Macbook recognizes my iPhone 6S just fine via USB).

The Android device is a Samsung Note 3, and I expected when I plugged it into the Mac it would show up in the Devices section of Finder.  It does not.

I tried a coworkers Android device, and the Mac was not able to see that either.

Both Android devices were getting power from the connection.  But I am not seeing them in Finder.

How can I connect my Android so I can see it in Finder on my Mac?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need an app for OS X/macOS to transfer files from an Android phone to your Mac.

Try [Android File Transfer](https://www.android.com/filetransfer/) from Google.

Also, a [suggestion from another forum](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/9193/phone-not-visible-to-finder-on-mac-suddenly) is:

> Try disabling `Settings -> Applications -> Development -> USB
>   debugging` in conjunction with setting `Settings -> Applications ->
>   USB settings` to Mass storage.

Answer (score 1):

If Android File Transfer doesn't work (which I've found it doesn't with all Android phones), I've long used [AirDroid](https://www.airdroid.com) as a third-party solution for transferring files and other information from your phone over WiFi. It requires installing an app on both the phone and the Mac, but it's free and it works well.